# Ruby sort by object's attribute based on keyword string

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a string called `sortKeyword`. I want to sort an array of objects by their attributes, but which attribute to sort on depends on `sortKeyword`.

Ex: when `sortKeyword` is 'name' I want to sort on the objects' 'name' attribute, when `sortKeyword` is 'age' I want to sort on the objects' age attribute, etc...

There are 10 possible values for `sortKeyword`, so naturally I'd rather not have a 10-case switch statement. Is there a better way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: You should use `snake_case` for variable names.

Comment: What do you mean by "attribute"? Do you mean an instance variable `@foo`, a method `foo`, or a getter you defined with `attr_reader :foo`?

Comment: I mean an instance variable that I have defined with an `attr_reader` so I can access it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use `public_send` method

```
array.sort_by { |item| item.public_send(sort_keyword) }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send

Comment: `.sort_by(&keyword)` or `.sort_by(&keyword.to_sym) ` if  `keyword` is a string.

Comment: In any case, please make sure that your keyword is filtered to only include the options you allow; you don't want user input to call arbitrary methods.

Comment: This assumes the instance variables have getters.

Comment: Yes @CarySwoveland, I took it for granted

Comment: Seems granted was good enough *"I mean an instance variable that I have defined with an `attr_reader` so I can access it"* - OP Comment from above

Comment: @engineersmnky, I missed that comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

In [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) one might get attributes of an object via `attributes` getter. In plain old good ruby, please refer to the answer by @Ursus.

```
array.sort_by { |e| e.attributes[SORTER] }
```

Comment: `attributes`? This doesn't seem to be a Rails question.

Comment: @Stefan oh, my bad, I seem to be too addicted to the fact that nearly every single question here is [tag:ruby-on-rails]. Will put a comment.

Comment: Keep in mind `attributes` can be a fairly expensive function since it returns a new hash on each call, something that makes it inefficient when called aggressively.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_em(arr, attr)
  arr.sort_by { |e| e.instance_variable_get "@#{attr}" }
end
```

Let's try it.

```
class Pets
  def initialize(x,y,z)
    @dog = x
    @cat = y
    @pig = z
  end
end

a = Pets.new(1, 3, 2)
  #=> #<Pets:0x00000001be8560 @dog=1, @cat=3, @pig=2>
b = Pets.new(2, 1, 3)
  #=> #<Pets:0x00000001bdec68 @dog=2, @cat=1, @pig=3>
c = Pets.new(3, 2, 1)
  #=> #<Pets:0x00000001bd61a8 @dog=3, @cat=2, @pig=1>
arr = [a, b, c]

sort_em(arr, "dog")
  #=> [#<Pets:0x00000001be8560 @dog=1, @cat=3, @pig=2>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001bdec68 @dog=2, @cat=1, @pig=3>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001bd61a8 @dog=3, @cat=2, @pig=1>]
sort_em(arr, "cat")
  #=> [#<Pets:0x00000001bdec68 @dog=2, @cat=1, @pig=3>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001bd61a8 @dog=3, @cat=2, @pig=1>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001be8560 @dog=1, @cat=3, @pig=2>]
sort_em(arr, "pig")
  #=> [#<Pets:0x00000001bd61a8 @dog=3, @cat=2, @pig=1>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001be8560 @dog=1, @cat=3, @pig=2>,
  #    #<Pets:0x00000001bdec68 @dog=2, @cat=1, @pig=3>]
```